# UFW denies SSH even though rules allow

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi, firewall, vpn, ufw

I have recently configured my RaspberryPi 3 to only allow connections through VPN. I would however like to open it for SSH connections from anywhere. The rules below should allow traffic on port 22, however as soon as I enable ufw I can no longer connect from anywhere but a local IP (the rules configuring local access work fine).
(Router Firewall is configured correctly)

```
root@raspberrypi:~# ufw status verbose
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), deny (outgoing), disabled (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
192.168.178.0/24           ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
22/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             

Anywhere                   ALLOW OUT   Anywhere on tun0          
192.168.178.0/24           ALLOW OUT   Anywhere                  
31.13.190.247 443/tcp      ALLOW OUT   Anywhere                  
Anywhere (v6)              ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6) on tun0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My error was having openvpn active.